# How to implement the returnurl like SO in PHP?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, returnurl

It should also work after url rewriting.

Is it possible?Otherwise I can only hardcode everything.

Comment: This is an unclear question.  Please edit it to describe what you are trying to do in more detail.

Comment: Have you tried log in and log out of SO?

Comment: So you're trying to create a login screen that a user is redirected to for login and after login returned to the page he was going to?

Comment: Yes,that's what I'm gonna do.

Comment: @Mask: that's what question should say then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to create a login system with redirection you need to use the HTTP_REFERER header to find out where the user came from so you can send him back there.  The best way to do this is, in your login form use something like this:

```
//- Login.php
<?php
    if ($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'])
    {
        //- Run username and password verifying script
        header("Location: ".$_POST['returnurl']);
    }
    $RedirectURL = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
?>
<form action="/login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="hidden" name="returnurl" value="<?php echo $RedirectURL; ?>" />
</form>
```

Please note that some ISPs, browsers or proxies will strip out the referer header, so you can't rely on it to work perfectly for every user.  If you use an if statement to check whether the header exists or not, you can send those users back to the homepage or whatever.

**EDIT**

If you're looking to use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] it should be set to the pretty URL after a rewrite if you're running Apache.  If you're running IIS, in which case you need to check for $_SERVER['X_HTTP_ORIGINAL_URL'].  Something like this:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SERVER['X_HTTP_ORIGINAL_URL']))
        $ReturnURL = $_SERVER['X_HTTP_ORIGINAL_URL'];
    else
        $ReturnURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    header("Location: /login.php?returnurl=".$ReturnURL);
?>
```

and

```
//- Login.php
<?php
    if ($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'])
    {
        //- Run username and password verifying script
        header("Location: ".$_POST['returnurl']);
    }
    $RedirectURL = isset($_GET['returnurl'] ? $_GET['returnurl'] : "/index.php";
?>
<form action="/login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="hidden" name="returnurl" value="<?php echo $RedirectURL; ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: This can be done extremely with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],but it won't work when url_rewriting is enabled.