# how to redirect a user to original page after login?

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement the returnurl like SO in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599379/how-to-implement-the-returnurl-like-so-in-php)

I am trying to make it so that when a non-logged in user is browsing my site and clicks on a link they are taken to the login page (which opens up in a jQuery lightbox window) and after login in they are taken back to the previous/original page they was on.

I have tried using this simple code to try and achieve this but when I use this it won't bring up the login page and goes straight to previous/original page so the users not able to login.

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
{
  header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

Here's all of my login script code:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" target="_top"  >
  <div class="row email">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($email); ?>" />
  </div>
  <div class="row password">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="<?php echo htmlentities($email); ?>" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-login" value="Login >
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
  if (logged_in())
  {
    redirect_to("dashboard.php");
  }

  include_once("includes/form_functions.php");

  // START FORM PROCESSING
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.
    $errors = array();

    // perform validations on the form data
    $required_fields = array('email', 'password');
    $errors = array_merge($errors, check_required_fields($required_fields, $_POST));

    $fields_with_lengths = array('email' => 30, 'password' => 30);
    $errors = array_merge($errors, check_max_field_lengths($fields_with_lengths, $_POST));

    $email = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['email']));
    $password = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['password']));
    $hashed_password = md5($password);

    if ( empty($errors) ) {
      // Check database to see if email and the hashed password exist there.
      $query = "SELECT id, email, close_account ";
      $query .= "FROM ptb_users ";
      $query .= "WHERE email = '{$email}' ";
      $query .= "AND password = '{$hashed_password}' ";
      $query .= "AND close_account = '0' ";
      $query .= "LIMIT 1";
      $result_set = mysql_query($query);
      confirm_query($result_set);
      if (mysql_num_rows($result_set) == 1) {
        // email/password authenticated
        // and only 1 match
        $found_user = mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $found_user['id'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $found_user['email'];
        $_SESSION['sub_expires'] = $found_user['subscription_expires'];

        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET user_online='Online' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."") 
                or die(mysql_error());


        redirect_to("dashboard.php");
      } else {
        // email/password combo was not found in the database
        $message = "<div class=\"infobox\"><strong>Email/Password combination incorrect.</strong><br />"
                .= "Please make sure your caps lock key is off and try again.</div><br/>";
      }
    } else {
      if (count($errors) == 1) {
        $message = "<div class=\"infobox\">There was 1 error in the form.<div>";
      } else {
        $message = "<div class=\"infobox\">There were " . count($errors) . " errors in the form.<div>";
      }
    }
  } else { // Form has not been submitted.
    if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == 1) {
      $message = "<div class=\"infobox\">You are now logged out.</div>";
    } 
    $email = "";
    $password = "";
  }
?>
<?php if (!empty($message)) {echo "<p class=\"message\">" . $message . "</p>";} ?>
<?php if (!empty($errors)) { display_errors($errors); } ?>
```

Comment: User is redirected to login page because HTTP_REFERRER will contain login page obviously.

Comment: use hidden field in the form with the value of $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and after login use that field to redirect.

Answer (score 2):

When someone tries to access a page that requires authentication, store that URL in a $_SESSION variable. Then redirect them to the login page. After login check to see if that $_SESSION variable exists. If it does, redirect them back to that URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can login with the help of AJAX and after successful login just reload the page. That will be more helpful in many ways.

e.g. If username/password is wrong, errors may be visible on the query lighbox window rather than wait for page load to show the errors.